# Apache2 fails to restart, 'configtest' failed in 'systemctl status' logs

Tags: server, ssh, apache2, webserver

trying to start my apache2 after my web server down from terminal

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

but it say

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

i try run `journalctl -xe` and it say

```
Nov 11 15:39:39 sd-101534 sshd[7011]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Nov 11 15:39:39 sd-101534 sshd[7013]: Failed password for root from 58.218.198.169 port 61692 ssh2
Nov 11 15:39:39 sd-101534 sshd[7013]: Received disconnect from 58.218.198.169 port 61692:11:  [preauth]
Nov 11 15:39:39 sd-101534 sshd[7013]: Disconnected from 58.218.198.169 port 61692 [preauth]
Nov 11 15:39:39 sd-101534 sshd[7013]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=58.218.198.169  user=root
Nov 11 15:39:40 sd-101534 sshd[7015]: Failed password for root from 58.242.83.32 port 58820 ssh2
Nov 11 15:39:43 sd-101534 sshd[7035]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=58.242.83.20  user=root
Nov 11 15:39:43 sd-101534 sshd[7015]: Failed password for root from 58.242.83.32 port 58820 ssh2
Nov 11 15:39:43 sd-101534 sshd[7015]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 58.242.83.32 port 58820 ssh2 [preauth]
Nov 11 15:39:43 sd-101534 sshd[7015]: Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Nov 11 15:39:43 sd-101534 sshd[7015]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=58.242.83.32  user=root
Nov 11 15:39:43 sd-101534 sshd[7015]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Nov 11 15:39:45 sd-101534 sshd[7035]: Failed password for root from 58.242.83.20 port 37618 ssh2
Nov 11 15:39:48 sd-101534 sshd[7035]: Failed password for root from 58.242.83.20 port 37618 ssh2
Nov 11 15:39:48 sd-101534 sshd[7039]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=58.242.83.32  user=root
Nov 11 15:39:50 sd-101534 sshd[7039]: Failed password for root from 58.242.83.32 port 17432 ssh2
Nov 11 15:39:50 sd-101534 sshd[7035]: Failed password for root from 58.242.83.20 port 37618 ssh2
Nov 11 15:39:51 sd-101534 sshd[7037]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=58.218.198.169  user=root
Nov 11 15:39:52 sd-101534 sshd[7037]: Failed password for root from 58.218.198.169 port 48911 ssh2
Nov 11 15:39:52 sd-101534 sshd[7039]: Failed password for root from 58.242.83.32 port 17432 ssh2
Nov 11 15:39:53 sd-101534 sshd[7035]: Failed password for root from 58.242.83.20 port 37618 ssh2
Nov 11 15:39:55 sd-101534 sudo[7041]:   jazuly : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/jazuly ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
Nov 11 15:39:55 sd-101534 sudo[7041]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by jazuly(uid=0)
```

then i run `nano /var/log/apache2/error.log`

i got this

```
$[Sat Nov 11 15:31:10.188122 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 797] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

i run `sudo systemctl status apache2.service`

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-11-11 15:42:06 CET; 16min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 6744 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25897 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7132 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 11 15:42:06 sd-101534 apache2[7132]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Nov 11 15:42:06 sd-101534 apache2[7132]: Output of config test was:
Nov 11 15:42:06 sd-101534 apache2[7132]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 12 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf:
Nov 11 15:42:06 sd-101534 apache2[7132]: Invalid command 'MazClients', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Nov 11 15:42:06 sd-101534 apache2[7132]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Nov 11 15:42:06 sd-101534 apache2[7132]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Nov 11 15:42:06 sd-101534 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 11 15:42:06 sd-101534 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 11 15:42:06 sd-101534 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 11 15:42:06 sd-101534 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

what i have to do to make my web go back to normal.

Comment: Please include the output of `sudo systemctl status apache2.service`. The issue is unrelated to ssh; probably some configuration setting stops apache2 from starting.

Comment: question edited

Comment: my web go down after so many proccess from `/usr/sbin/mysqld` i check my dedicate status from `htop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an invalid config option, which is why Apache can't start and why it says `'configtest' failed`.  Actually reading the output from `systemctl status` usually is enough to identify such problems, and identify core reasons that your software isn't running properly.  I see it all the time.

That said, this is the specific error as detailed in your `systemctl` status output:

```
Nov 11 15:42:06 sd-101534 apache2[7132]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 12 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf:
Nov 11 15:42:06 sd-101534 apache2[7132]: Invalid command 'MazClients', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Edit the file that it references (`/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf`), and try replacing `MazClients` with `MaxClients`, then attempt to start Apache again.  It looks to me like your actual issue is with MPM Prefork and not MySQL.